# How do I make search bar fit within the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to get a search bar integrated into the navigation bar. When you the SearchView is initialised from a NavigationLink, a "back" button is there by default. I want the search bar to be directly next to this. At the moment it is under this.

This feels like it should have a simple solution but I can't seem to find a clear and simple one.

Here is some reproducible code for testing:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {                
                NavigationLink(destination: SearchView()) {
                    Text("Go to search view")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Placeholder + search results go here")
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .background(.red)
                    
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}
```

Here are some images showing what it looks like and what I want it to look like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple `NavigationView`s. Remove the one in `SearchView`